# Slider for multiple items from JSON with VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, slider

I have this code here:

```js
    const section = document.querySelector('section');

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let sourceData = {"offers":[
    {"name": "Porsche", "price": "99999999", "currency":"$", "imgURL": "https://porsche.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/macan-porsche-polska.jpg"},
    {"name": "Multipla", "price": "990", "currency":"$", "imgURL": "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Fiat_Multipla_front_20080825.jpg/1200px-Fiat_Multipla_front_20080825.jpg"},
  {"name": "Boeing 747", "price": "990999999", "currency":"$", "imgURL": "//media.istockphoto.com/photos/boing-747-taking-off-picture-id458711123"}
]};
    request.open("GET", sourceData);
    request.responseType = 'json';


    request.onload = function() {
    const banner = request.response;
    completeAd(banner);
    }

    function completeAd(obj) {
        const offers = obj['offers']; 
        let rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * offers.length)); 

        const singleAd = document.createElement('article');
        singleAd.className = "article";
        const name = document.createElement('p');
        const price = document.createElement('h2');
        const imgURL = document.createElement('img')
        const buttonCheck = document.createElement('button');
        buttonCheck.className = "buttonCheck";
        
        imgURL.src = "http:" + offers[rand].imgURL
        price.textContent = offers[rand].price + " " + offers[rand].currency;
        name.textContent = offers[rand].name;
        buttonCheck.textContent = "Check"

        singleAd.appendChild(imgURL);
        singleAd.appendChild(name);
        singleAd.appendChild(price);
        singleAd.appendChild(buttonCheck);

        section.appendChild(singleAd);   

        let i = 0;          // Start Point
        // Images Array
        let time = 3000;    // Time Between Switch
            
        // Change Image
        function changeAd(){
        document.article.src = offers[i];

        // Check If Index Is Under Max
        if(i < offersAd.length - 1){
        // Add 1 to Index
        i++; 
        } else { 
            // Reset Back To O
            i = 0;
        }

        // Run function every x seconds
        setTimeout(changeAd(), time);
}

// Run function when page loads
window.onload = changeAd();


    }
```

```css
.banner {
    width: 160px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

#logo {
    padding-top: 30px;
    max-width: 140px;
}

.article {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 520px;
    width: 150px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
}

.ads img {
    max-height: auto;
    width: 140px;
}

.buttonCheck {
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 64%, 0.932);
    border: none;
    content: "Check";
    color: white;
}

.ads p {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="banner.css">
    <title>Banner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <section class="ads" name="slide">
        </section>    
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

First of all, this snipper doesn't work, as I'm using data directly from JSON. I tried to recreate, but needs to update the code around the source and I'm not sure how.

Secondly, what is more important for me, I tried to make a slider from those 3 offers in sourceData(JSON). What am I doing wrong? IS this even a correct way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the host you want to make "GET"?

Comment: It's an open connection for retrieving some simple data from JSON